# SARIMAX - Summary table coefficient signs are reversed when calling them

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, arima

I've fit a SARIMAX model using statsmodels as follows

```
mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(ratingCountsRSint,order=(2,0,0),seasonal_order=(1,0,0,52),enforce_stationarity=False,enforce_invertibility=False, freq='W')
results = mod.fit()
print(results.summary().tables[1])
```

In the results table I have a coefficient ar.S.L52 that shows as 0.0163. When I try to retrieve the coefficient using

```
seasonalAR=results.polynomial_seasonal_ar[52]
```

I get -0.0163. I'm wondering why the sign has turned around. The same thing happens with polynomial_ar. In the documentation it says that polynomial_seasonal_ar gives the "array containing seasonal autoregressive lag polynomial coefficients". I would have guessed that I should get exactly the same as in the summary table. Could someone clarify how that comes about and whether the actual coefficient of the lag is positive or negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use an AR(1) model as an example, but the same principle applies to a seasonal model.

We typically write the AR(1) model as:

y_t = \phi_1 y_{t-1} + \varespilon_t

The parameter estimated by Statsmodels is \phi_1, and that is what is presented in the summary table.

When writing the AR(1) model in lag-polynomial form, we usually write it like:

\phi(L) y_t = \varepsilon_t

where \phi(L) = 1 - \phi L, and L is the lag operator. The coefficients of this lag polynomial are (1, -\phi). These coefficients are what are presented in the `polynomial` attributes in the results object.